# PDFKIT custom fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

Is there any way to print pdf with PDFKit and custom font?

In css I have:

```
 @font-face {
font-family: 'ChaparralProRegular';
src: url("path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.eot");
src: url("path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
url("path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.ttf")  format("truetype"),
url("path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.svg#ChaparralProRegular") format("svg");
```

Above code works fine when render as html but printing to pdf with PDFKit use standard font. 
Any clues?

Comment: JFI did you provided media screen with your stylesheet and also there is options to attach stylesheet in `wkthmltopdf` to attach stylesheet I guess pdfkit too support it ,Yes it does `kit.stylesheets << '/path_to_your_stylesheet`

Answer (score 1):

I guess your pdfkit just can't find where your font files are. I had the same issue with images in pdf.
Try to substitute all your urls for font files with local file paths:

```
url("#{Rails.root}/path_to_font/chaparralpro-regular-webfont.eot");
```